# selection sort algo in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, data-structures, selection-sort

As we all know that **selection sort** in DS is done by comparing the elements and then swapping the smallest to the beginning using a **temporary variable**. I have learnt a **new way** to swap is by just **changing the array positions**. I need your view and suggestions that if it effects the overall performance of the function or we should follow the **traditional** way.

the traditional way of sorting the array using selection sort is

```
const fun = (arr) => {
  console.log(arr)
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let min = i
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)//1
    {
      if (arr[j] < arr[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
      let temp = arr[i]
      arr[i] = arr[min]
      arr[min] = temp

    }

  } return arr
}
console.log(fun([23, 564, 4, 34, 45, 7, 56, 878, 5, 1]))
```

**the way i tried is below**

```
const fun = (arr) => {
  console.log(arr)
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)//1
    {
      if (arr[j] < arr[i]) {
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]] // here I swapped the array elements **
      }

    }

  } return arr
}
console.log(fun([23, 4, 34, 7, 56, 878, 5, 1]))
```

Comment: There's several online tools you can use to compare performance of JS scripts. For example: https://jsbench.me/hgla5dllya/1 shows that your new version is around 35% faster.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your tests are run on different arrays, I'm seeing only a 2% difference when run on the same sample.

Comment: @pilchard well spotted - I simply copied the code in the question. I was wondering why the delta was so great. The average performance difference I've seen over 10 runs is that the second version is 0.78% faster. Within that I had 2 instances where the first version was faster.

Comment: glad to share its the fastest way to swap the array indexes

Comment: It's not the fastest way to swap, the temp variable will always be faster especially on large arrays. More importantly you've change the logic in the second example by not updating the `min` index.

Comment: can u please help me how to check it. When I checked it was 24% efficient